# What method is called right before the application exits?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

We are dealing with a problem of an application restarting too often (once every couple of hours). This results in the first visitor having a long load time every few hours. Furthermore, we have a separate server that handles queued messages, it may be down for a day without us knowing because the application will exit for no apparent reason.

Is there any event or method we could hook into to log when the application exits, why it exits, and possibly instruct it to restart?

Comment: It's already restarting (otherwise you wouldn't get that slow 1st page).

Comment: did you look into applicaion pool timeout (from the IIS). by default its 20 min.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - True, the website is restarting, but our queue server (also an mvc app) doesn't restart because it is not supposed to be visited. I'd also like it to restart instantly so the user doesn't get a slow first page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS will shut down any app pool that is idle for a period of time.  IIS will also recycle the app pool when it detects certain kinds of errors, etc...

You can certainly hook into the Application_End() event, however it is not guaranteed that this will be called in all cases.  For instance, if the app is forcefully terminated it will not get called.

In more recent versions of IIS, you can configure IIS to keep your app "warm".  You can also create a scheduled job that just touches your homepage every so often.

Comment: Our apps are set to the default recycling (Fixed interval, every 1740 minutes). Is there another process that shuts it down?

Comment: I found the `Idle Time-out (minutes)` setting. It is indeed set to 20 minutes by default. I'll monitor this weekend to see if it actually shuts down my thread on my queue app, but for the website it should be fine with that value. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is application_end, which gets fired when your IIS pool is recycled, or the application gets unloaded. Applications reload themselves when a required file changes as well.